# Retrieve the checked value from SQL Server database to checkedListBox

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2017

Here is my code when adding the checked items to database, the datatype is `Bit`:

```
Dim command As SqlClient.SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = "insert into tblActionTaken (A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, Idnum) values (@a1, @a2, @a3, @a4, @a5, @idnum)"

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", A1)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", A2)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", A3)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", A4)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", A5)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", Me.CCLA_File_NumberLabel2.Text)

command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

How do I retrieve it from the database to `checkedlistbox`? For example, I have 5 checkboxes inside `checkedlistbox` and then I checked 3 check boxes. When I retrieve the data from the database, the 3 check boxes should show checked and the other 2 unchecked.

Comment: You retrieve the data from the database the same way you do any other data.  You set the checked state of the items in the `CheckedListBox` the same way you do any items.  There's no special magic to it.  It's simple logic.  Exactly how you think you would do it is how you would do it.

Comment: thank you for your help, I figure out how to do it, thanks for always giving me idea on how to do it